# How to prevent dropdown menu being hidden behind buttons with badges in Spectre CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using [Spectre CSS](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components.html#dropdowns) dropdown menus in a list and also putting [badges](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components.html#badges) on them dynamically using [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) data binding. I am doing it by wrapping the `div.dropdown` in a `span` which conditionally has the `badge` class.  My problem is that the menu pane is hidden behind any button which has an active badge. I played around with the z-index on the `ul.menu` but it has no effect. Anyone know what is the cause and/or how to fix it?  And for extra credit... I noticed that when the `active` class is on a dropdown button with a badge on it the badge is behind the button instead of in front of it, which seems wrong to me. It does not do that for a regular button only a dropdown one.

Here is the (stripped-down) html:

```
<div class="column col-2">
<template v-for="(o, i) in list">
    <span :class="{badge: o.qty > 0}" :data-badge="o.qty">
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn" :class="{active: i == current}">
                    {{o.name}}
                </button>
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" :class="{active: i == current}" tabindex="0">
                    <i class="icon icon-caret"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"> ... </li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</template>
</div>
```

And here is a picture of the result:

[image: Screen capture of dropdown menu issue]

Hmmm... seems there is no tag for Spectre CSS and I can't create one.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with z-index being set on elements that were supposed to be shown above avatar images and active buttons, which in spectre by default are at a higher z-index level.  By changing our CSS to override those items back to z-index:auto, and removing our other z-index mods, the problem (actually both problems) is fixed.